# HTML JAVASCRIPT multiple Draggable <div> icons?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a script I was making for the development of a programing website of links related to programing. It is suppose to be a desktop with icons that can be dragged around the desktop and clicking on them leads to their respective websites. With 1 icon it works fine, with 2 icons the second will not move. anyone know why?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link charset="UTF-8">

<style>
p,a{font-size:18px;}

img {
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
}

body {
    border:2px solid black;
    z-index:-1;
    background:linear-gradient(#9d4bdd,#7c3ba3,#6425b1);
    position:auto;
}

#mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background:linear-gradient(white,grey,white);
    border:2px solid black;
    padding:10px;
}

#mydivheader {
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>

<body>

    <div id="mydiv">
        <a target="_blank" title="Microsoft Learn" href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/">
            <img src="C:\Users\Mr\Downloads\Programmy\Html\Websties\Christophertm\dt\mslogo1.jpg"></a>
        <h5>Microsoft Learn</h5>
    </div>

    <div id="mydiv">
        <a target="_blank" title="Visual Studio" href="https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/">
            <img src="C:\Users\Mr\Downloads\Programmy\Html\Websties\Christophertm\dt\vslogo1.jpg"></a>
        <h5>Visual Studio</h5>
    </div>

<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));


function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
</script>

    <!-- <div id="mydiv">
        <a target="_blank" title="Microsoft Learn" href=" ">
            <img src="C:\Users\Mr\Downloads\Programmy\Html\Websties\Christophertm\dt\mslogo1.jpg">
        </a>
        <h5>Microsoft Learn</h5>
    </div>
    
    <div id="mydiv1">
        <a target="_blank" title="Visual Studio" href="https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/">
            <img src="C:\Users\Mr\Downloads\Programmy\Html\Websties\Christophertm\dt\vslogo1.jpg">
        </a>
        <h5>Visual Studio</h5>
    </div>

    <div id="mydiv2">
        <a target="_blank" title="Google Code" href="https://code.google.com/">
            <img src="C:\Users\Mr\Downloads\Programmy\Html\Websties\Christophertm\dt\googlecodelogo1.jpg">
        </a>
        <h5>Google Code</h5>
    </div> -->

</body>
```

I tried to duplicate the   but did not want to duplicate the  for every icon.

Comment: `id` should be used to uniquely identify an element. You've got 2 elements with the same id. Instead, please use `class` to specify your drag-able elements and `document.getElementsByClassName("myDiv")` to get all those elements and call `dragElement` for each.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Post your questions separately please

Answer (score 0):

The fix was very simple making use of event listeners. Here you go.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link charset="UTF-8">

<style>
p,a{font-size:18px;}

img {
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
}

body {
    border:2px solid black;
    z-index:-1;
    background:linear-gradient(#9d4bdd,#7c3ba3,#6425b1);
    position:auto;
}

#mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background:linear-gradient(white,grey,white);
    border:2px solid black;
    padding:10px;
}

#mydivheader {
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>

<body>

    <div id="mydiv">
        <a target="_blank" title="Microsoft Learn" href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/">
            <img src="C:\Users\Mr\Downloads\Programmy\Html\Websties\Christophertm\dt\mslogo1.jpg"></a>
        <h5>Microsoft Learn</h5>
    </div>

    <div id="mydiv">
        <a target="_blank" title="Visual Studio" href="https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/">
            <img src="C:\Users\Mr\Downloads\Programmy\Html\Websties\Christophertm\dt\vslogo1.jpg"></a>
        <h5>Visual Studio</h5>
    </div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("mousedown",mouseDown);
    function mouseDown(info) {
        var elmnt
        var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
        if (info.target.id == "mydiv") {
            elmnt = info.target
            dragMouseDown()
        }
        function dragMouseDown(e) {
        console.log(e)
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }

    function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // calculate the new cursor position:
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        // set the element's new position:
        elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
        elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    }

    function closeDragElement() {
        /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
    }
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Most epic Mr. Texan!  I was trying not to replicate classes and CSS for every link icon! My JavaScript is not that great and the JS is from https://www.w3schools.com, you might show them your refinements? Most helpful, Thanks many